# how i can close the keyboard when the user press the back icon in my toolbar?

Tags: android, view, keyboard, listener, searchview

i have try to show by my code the keyboard because the closeListener and the onExpandListener doesn't work.Where i have fail? There is a method that can be invoke when the users press the back button of the toolbar?

image of back toolbar button --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDZlu.jpg

this is my java code;
the class that have the searchview:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

SearchView searchView = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    //Title and subtitle
    toolbar.setTitle("Magazzino Chimica");

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"premuto",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (R.id.action_search == item.getItemId()){
        searchView.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager tastiera = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        tastiera.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
    return true;
}
```

my searchable.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/label_ricerca"
    android:hint="@string/suggerimento_ricerca" >
</searchable>
```

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.developer.eliax1996.databasegestionariochimica" >

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Search results activity -->
    <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="cerca"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

how i can close the keyboard when the users press the back button in the toolbar?

Edit:
I tried but when the app is running, if I press the button indicated by the image, the program doesn't pass in this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {}
```

Edit x2:
I tried but it passes to the method only after 2 clicks, i put the project file online :), sorry for the xml because i am italian and all the writes in the xml resource are italian, but there are only 4 writes :)

project files --> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B907WWO7eA5bZ1BTUmlIekxDaGs/view?usp=sharing

Edit x3:
I followed your advice, but doesn't jet work, can you try my code? :)

Comment: I have edited my answer. You need to add the back arrow to your acion bar by using the method in my answer. Then all presses will be sent to onOptionsItemSelected() automatically.

Comment: You shouldn't use a 'NavigationOnClickListener' and 'onOptionsItemSelected'. Remove the listener and everything should work fine by using 'onOptionsItemSelected'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu), add this line:

```
// This will add the back arrow to your action bar.
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In your `onOptionsItemSelected()`, add this:

```
// Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
    hideSoftKeyboard(this);
    // finish(), NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(activity) or something like that
}
```

with the method to hide the keyboard:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onOptionsItemSelected` method of the activity to intercept the click on `android.R.id.home`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        searchView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);`enter code here`
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }

        }, 300);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```